# C# Listboxes Copy not Move

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

I need to COPY items from Listbox1 to Listbox2.  I'm using this MOVE code snippet.  For the single item (btnAdd1), I just comment out the 'Remove' line and all works as expected.  However for the multiple select (btnAdd2), if I comment out the 'Remove' line the program hangs ... however if I leave it in, it works.  Any ideas?

```
private void btnAdd1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select an Item");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            }
         }
    }

    private void btnAdd2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Multiple Items");
        }
        else
        {
            while(listBox1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
            {
                if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[0]);
                    // If this line is missing, the program hangs
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to run it in the debugger to be sure, but I suspect that  `while(listBox1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)` never becomes false for some reason.  Either that or removing an item form the list does not take it out of the `SelectedItems` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have a while loop. the condition for while loop will be true if you remove that line.
your code should be like this:

```
foreach(var item in listbox1.SelectedItems)
if (!listbox2.items.contain(item)
    listbox2.items.add(item);
```

Comment: But then the item is not getting removed from `listbox1`, and it's likely that removing an item will invalidate the `foreach` since the underlying collection will have been modified.

Comment: Change my foreach to for and count from top to bottom. I forgot you wanted to move. but its also a simple one. It only needs a bit of change

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've incorporated some of these approaches and now everything works just like I want.  Here's the final code.

```
private void btnAdd2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Multiple Items");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```